# Can't seem to install the "devtools" package

Tags: r, devtools, htmltools

I need to install Devtools so i can download the 0.5.4 htmltools package from github, almost every package i try to install gives an error stating that the htmltools version i have is 0.5.2 but the package requires the 0.5.4 version, which i think is the github developers version, but i cant install devtools because it states this error message requiring for htmltools 0.5.4:

```
* installing *source* package 'bslib' ...
** package 'bslib' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'htmltools' 0.5.2 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.4 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execução interrompida
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'bslib'
* removing 'C:/Users/Rafael-PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/bslib'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bslib’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'callr' ...
** package 'callr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'processx' 3.5.3 is being loaded, but >= 3.6.1 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execução interrompida
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'callr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Rafael-PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/callr'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Rafael-PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/callr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execução interrompida
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/Users/Rafael-PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Rafael-PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'pkgload' ...
** package 'pkgload' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.3 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execução interrompida
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'pkgload'
* removing 'C:/Users/Rafael-PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/pkgload'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pkgload’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'pkgbuild' ...
** package 'pkgbuild' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'cli' 3.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execução interrompida
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'pkgbuild'
* removing 'C:/Users/Rafael-PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/pkgbuild'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pkgbuild’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'bslib' is not available for package 'pkgdown'
* removing 'C:/Users/Rafael-PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/pkgdown'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pkgdown’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'pkgbuild', 'pkgdown', 'pkgload' are not available for package 'devtools'
* removing 'C:/Users/Rafael-PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/devtools'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status
```

tried to install htmltools via CRAN but the error persisted.

Comment: What is your version of R? What happens if you run `install.packages("rlang")`?

Comment: Also, what platform are you on? Please give us your `sessionInfo()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jupyter notebook for R try to install the devtools package in anaconda command prompt. Try this code  install.packages("devtools") in anaconda prompt sometimes installing packages directly in notebook won't work and also check you R version is supported  for  devtools